# Returning model with association count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

### What I am returning

I have a query that returns a hash with the person's ID and how many episodes of a TV show they have been on:

```
Person.joins(:contributions)
.where('contributions.role_id = 2')
.where('contributions.episode_id IN (?)', self.episodes.pluck(:id)).limit(5)
.group(:person_id).order('count_all desc').count
```

Returns:

```
{26=>66, 14=>13, 17=>10, 30=>9, 9=>8}
```

(person with id 26 has been on 66 episodes)

---

### What I want to return

If I take off everything after the `.group` I get the actual person models in an array but (of courrse) they are unsorted and have no count.

```
[#<Person id: 26, first_name: "Natasha">, #<Person id: 1, first_name: "Steve"]
```

**Is there any way get the person record and the count?**
example:

```
[[ <Person id: 26, first_name: "Natasha">, 66 ], [<Person id: 1, first_name: "Steve", 13]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this works:

```
Person.joins(:contributions)
  .where('contributions.role_id = 2')
  .where('contributions.episode_id IN (?)', self.episodes.select(:id))
  .limit(5)
  .group(:person_id)
  .select('people.*, COUNT(*) AS count_all')
  .order('count_all desc')
```

This will add a field `count_all` on the models, which might be preferable to your desired output. If you need that specific output, you could add:

```
.map { |r| [r, r.count_all] }
```

to the end of the query above.

One thing to note: you might be able to use `select` rather than `pluck` in the `episodes` part to prevent a second query.

**EDIT**

The above seems to work fine in some limited testing, even though the generated SQL is kind of wrong (we're selecting non-aggregated, non-group-by fields).

You could also assign the value of your initial query to `hsh` and then:

```
Person.where(id: hsh.keys).map do |o|
  [ o, hsh[o.id] ]
end.sort_by { |ar| ar[-1] }.reverse
```

To get the output you like with only one additional query.